# Combining lossless scripts imports

Tags: python

I have 6 scripts that I want to run sequentially.

1 configuration file (import, driver path, other settings)
and 5 consecutive scripts. How can I run all 6 scripts so that they work in turn as if it were 1 script?

Answer (score 1):

Import modules containing these scripts in your code, then run their functions sequentially.

```
import script1, script2, script3
script1.run()
script2.run()
# ...
```

You’ll need to create the corresponding function `run()` in each of the modules (`script1.py`, `script2.py`, etc.)

Comment: corresponding function run().. do not quite understand. What to create?

Comment: @keepomen: Create a function run() in each of your script files containing the script. Then, call it from your main code with scriptX.run() - after importing it (see my answer.)